# Can Core project in Clean Architecture depends on nuget package?

Tags: domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

I have Core project where I need to do some cryptographic operations, e.g. verification of SHA256. What can I do if it's Core project, so it shouldn't depend on anything? I have to write my own cryptographic functions that are resistant to e.g. side-channel attack? This causes security problems.

So what to do? Can my Core project depend on a nuget package if I use Clean Architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guideline regarding dependencies is to keep the core project as simple as possible so that most of its logic is about solving the business problem.

By keeping it simple, it's much easier to express which part of the business domain the classes solve. It's also easy to write focused tests that prove that the code can solve the correct part of the business problem.

To me, preventing attacks is not a part of that. It's something that should be done on inbound API calls before the domain is called. I would put that logic in application services. Those services can, of course, live in the Core project but not in any of the bounded contexts.

Comment: But what if verifying the hash is part of my business logic?

Comment: Then it should be there. The number of dependencies doesn't matter. What's matter is that core is a business-focused layer. The more dependencies you have, the harder it is to keep it clean (and testability decreases). That doesn't necessarily mean that no dependencies are allowed. Just that you should take care.

Comment: Hi @jgauffin, I am implementing clean architecture in my project (Domain, Application, Infrastructure, Persistance and Web). I need to encrypt my connectionString and API key using cryptography. Do you know which layer should I put this?

Comment: Nothing that is required to solve the customer problem, so it isn't part of the domain. And it's not required to expose the API or allow other endpoints to communicate the domain. So it's not part of application services. But it's meant to allow access to the database, hence infrastructure code.

Answer (score 1):

In Clean Architecture we try to keep the domain and application logic as independent from external libraries and frameworks as possible so that we do not  depend on their future development.

Nevertheless the application logic will have to interact with external libraries, services and other IO which is achieved via "dependency inversion": the application logic defines an interface which is implemented by the outer layers (infrastructure).

This was the application logic remains "clean" and can focus on decision making while you can still reuse external libraries and services.

A more detailed discussion of this topic you can find here: http://www.plainionist.net/Implementing-Clean-Architecture-Frameworks/